# Faster Algorithm for string comparing in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, string, methods

I have two sentences that needed to be compared to each-other.
The final result is how much percent one sentence contains in the other, my problem is that I have 100.000 records that need to be compared with lets say another 10. 
That is 1.000.000 loops, which in my algorithm is very slow.

This is the algorithm that I am using:

```
private double BreakStringsAndCheck(string s1, string s2)
{
    if (s1 == null || s2 == null || s1.Length == 0 || s2.Length == 0)
        return (double)0;
    string[] firstArray = s1.Split(' ');
    string[] secondArray = s2.Split(' ');
    if (firstArray.Length > secondArray.Length)
    {
        string[] tempArray = firstArray;
        firstArray = secondArray;
        secondArray = tempArray;
    }
    double value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.Length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < secondArray.Length; j++)
            value += firstArray[i] == secondArray[j] ? (double)100 : (double)0;
    return findLongest ? value : value / firstArray.Length;
}
```

It's a small method but it is not very fast. From my testing I can do 40-60 comparisons in 1 second, that is almost 5 hours for 1.000.000 loops.

Can some one think of another method or logic that is much faster than this?

Update:

I will try to explain the problem with more details.
I have database with more than 100.000 records, and every day I insert, and compare 10-20 new record in this database.
This records are sentences from 2 to 10 words and I need to write fast method that will compare this new records with those in database, the result should be percentage of how much one sentence contains the words from the other.

I need the records that has more than 70% word match.

I hope that I'm clear now.

Comment: You could try stuffing it in a Parallel.For or something? Just to see if it helps?

Comment: I will try it but I think that that does the same thing in the background.

Comment: By the first I see that you can use unsigned long instead of double. Type cast takes too much time.. Try to use ulong value = 0; ...

Comment: I need the result in double, thats why I use double.
But I will try to change it in long and compare the result.

Comment: return findLongest ? (double)value : (double)value / firstArray.Length;

Comment: @pece - I think if you give a bit more context to the problem, this will aid people in providing more suitable answers.

Comment: I've made update with more explanation.

Comment: Could a typo check algorithm like `Levenshtein distance` or http://siderite.blogspot.com/2007/04/super-fast-and-accurate-string-distance.html be useful?

Comment: I've try Levenshtein distance earlier, but its much slower.
I'll see the second one write now, and will try it.

Comment: What's the length of inputs? each sentence length?

Comment: Could you show us an example? It seems to me that the max score here is unbounded (that is you can have a sentence "a a a a a a" and if the database entry is "foo a bar baz boo bin" then you will score 100%).  If this isn't the intent you can add a `break;` in the inner for loop when the comparison is true.

Comment: Well the records are something like this:

CD 214/13-1 A;
DI 211/3 AB;
Jove Joveski preku Ivan Jovanov;
Jove Joveski;

The last two need to return 100%

Answer (score 6):

I'm not a C# programmer, but here are a few general tips:

1. Move the floating point arithmetic out of the loop.  You should be able to count the characters that match and do the division later.
2. You should be able to run each "long" loop in a separate thread of execution since the data is static.  I would spawn a separate thread for each of your "10" sentences and run them in parallel.
3. You might want to remove the call to `split` if you can.  Basically, remove any extra memory allocations.

The final thought is to grab an algorithms book or google for text processing algorithms.  This problem sounds like something that has been solved over and over again.  There is probably something in [AOCP v3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) that solves this problem.  You could also profile the code (not sure what types of profilers are available), but that probably won't yield substantial improvements.

Comment: re-writing it to use the words "in place" without the split might well be a good approach. It should reduce the memory allocation and consequent GC time and also be a bit faster anyway. Multiple threads will only help if there are multiple concurrent threads running (cores or CPUs) - otherwise this one should be CPU bound anyway.

Comment: I try removing the floating point, but the method is not much faster, almost the same.
I cannot separate threads because the values that I'm using are not the same, and not same number.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) method as an alternative. I have no idea about its performance but it looks like it may work

Comment: mhm, Interesting I'll definitely try it write now.

Comment: Using `Intersect` will give you a different score to the original algorithm if either array contains duplicates. I don't know whether that would be a problem for the OP or not.

Comment: @lukeH - good point, i did not see that implication.  However, if dups are not an issue, he could `Distinct` them.

Comment: I've try it with Intersect, its is still to slow.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd avoid creating the two arrays; the memory allocations will kill performance.

Try looking at the [string.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7tax739.aspx) function to find where the next space is in both strings, subtract that from the previous space location to work out the word length. If the two lengths are equal then use [string.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y.aspx) to see if the two sub-strings are equal. This will avoid memory allocations and only iterate through the strings once, so should be faster.

Also, as others have mentioned, definitely look at using the Parallel extensions.

Answer (score 0):

If you split the 10 records first, then you're finding a small number of strings in many larger strings. This seems to fit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Algorithms_using_finite_set_of_patterns

and the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) might work well for you

How long are the records?

EDIT:

This is an unnecessary switcharound - your comparison is symmetric wrt firstArray and secondArray

```
 if (firstArray.Length > secondArray.Length)
    {
        string[] tempArray = firstArray;
        firstArray = secondArray;
        secondArray = tempArray;
    }
```

instead, replace the return with

return findLongest ? value : (firstArray.Length > secondArray.Length) ? value/secondArray.length  : value / firstArray.Length);

only with something more readable :)

UPDATE after question update

So you could pre-process the 100,000 (e.g. to hash the words)? And only 10-20 change per day so keeping the preprocessed data up to date would be easy.

You definitely need to do something that uses the relatively-static nature of the 100,000. Even if you did the pre-processing just once per day, you could do the comparison with all of last days' records, then use your current slowish approach for any others added since the last preprocessing run. From what you say, there will be at most 10-20 of those

I think either the hashing idea, or building a Aho-Comisack trie from the corpus would give you much faster searching.

Comment: the records are from 2 to 10 strings

Comment: And the (approx) 10 that you need to compare them to are known up front? If so, build a Aho-Corisack tree and tag the complete words with which of the 10 records it occurs in. Then search for the words in each record and count matches found for ach of the 10 records? If the 100,000 are (relatively) fixed but the 10 vary instead, then the reverse technique might help, or you could hash all the words in all the records, then hash the words in the 10, and look for matches that way? How many unique words in all are there?

Comment: Are you comparing the same 10 to all 100,000? If so the above approach will work.

Comment: No, this 10 records are always different, and the another 100.000 are taken from database that is continuously filed with other records.

Comment: Ouch. then this is nasty. Are the words from a known set or are they all different too?

Comment: THen probably all you can do is tweaks that I and others have suggested. Can you explain the wider context? What's the purpose of these comparisons?

Comment: I've made an update to my question, I need to find if some of the new sentences are contained or containing 70, 80, 90 or 100% of the others in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Intersect example

```
private double BreakStringsAndCheck(string s1, string s2)
{
    var split1 = s1.Split(' ');
    return (double)split1.Intersect(s2.Split(' ')).Count() / split1.Count() * 100.0;
}
```

I would prefer to return the ratio 0.4 instead of 40.0 for:

```
var percent = BreakStringsAndCheck("Jan Banan går till GAIS.", "I Torsk på Tallin så var en annan Jan Banan med.");
```

I just realized that your algorithm always compares the shorter string to the longer. So your algorithm would return 40.0 even if the input parameters are switched like this

```
var percent = BreakStringsAndCheck("I Torsk på Tallin så var en annan Jan Banan med.", "Jan Banan går till GAIS.");
```

but my intersect example will return 18.18. I feel that this is more correct but if you really want your way then just add

```
if (s1.Length > s2.Length)
{
    var tmp = s2;
    s2 = s1;
    s1 = tmp;
}
```

to the beginning of the method.

**Presplitting**

```
var presplits = new List<string[]>() { s1.Split(' '), s2.Split(' '), s3.Split(' ') };
```

...

```
private static IEnumerable<double> StringsInString(IEnumerable<string[]> strings, string s2)
{
    return strings.Select(h => (double)h.Intersect(s2.Split(' ')).Count() / h.Count());
}
```

then loop over all your 100.000 strings in a `Parallel.For`.

PS. I think that you will have to downcase and remove `.`, `,` and so on from the strings to get a more correct ratio.
DS.

Comment: Using `Intersect` will give you a different score to the original algorithm if either array contains duplicates. I don't know whether that would be a problem for the OP or not.

Comment: I'am trying write now this Method with Intersect, well see how it goes

Comment: Be aware that it most probably do not return what you want, not exactly anyway. I left the answer here as an example and as something for you to get ideas from. `Mine("t t t", "t t") => 33.3, Yours("t t t", "t ") => 300.0`, `Mine("t t", "t t t") => 50.0, Yours("t t", "t t t") => 300.0`

Comment: Nothing with intersect, its still to slow, the comparing is little bit faster, but not much.

Comment: Try splitting your 10 strings in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Before performing any comparisons, preprocess the 100,000 rows.
Every word in the 100,000 rows is going to be a key in a `Dictionary<>` object, the value is going to be a list of id's (the id's of each row that word occurs on), e.g.

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> allWords
```

When "searching for a match", you keep a second dictionary, this one is keyed by row id, and it's value is an integer you'll increment.  e.g.

```
Dictionary<int, int> matches
```

You split the search string into words, and for each row id for each word you increment the value for that row id.

```
var searchWords = search.Split(" ");
foreach(var word in searchWord)
{
    foreach(var id in allWords[word])
        matches[id] += 1;
}
var bestRowId = (from m in matches orderby m.Value select m.Key).Last();
```

The row id with the greatest value is the best match.

It'll take some time up front to build the dictionary (but I'd guess not much more than for a single comparison), but it will be blindingly fast after that.

**NB:** The key to the speed here is that Dictionary will use the HashCode of the key it's storing, and the .net hash function for strings is excellent.

**Update**

If pre-processing on this order takes too long, then you can do a lighter pre-process.
As you read each of the 100,000 rows, split it into words, and sort the array of words. Then as you compare, split the string to compare and sort it also.
Your function then saves time because it isn't splitting each string multiple times, and your nested loops can be replaced with a loop for `min(words1.length, words2.length)`.

Comment: This is where I was going, but see the OP's responses to my answer - things change too much to allow pre-processing.

Comment: @Pece: Have profile both your and my solutions. Mine is faster if you're comparing 3 or more new strings, geometrically faster for each comparison above 3. Let me know if you'd like to see code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach. I'm guessing that when you compare 10 sentences against 100'000 sentences, there are going to be a large number where no words match and % = 0. Instead of always performing 100'000 comparisons, find those sentences in the 100'000 where at least one word matches and only compare them.

Create (once) a dictionary of all the words in the 100'000 sentences.

Each entry is a list L of sentences containing this word.

```
tobetested=empty
For each s in the 10 sentences
  for each word in s
    if dictionary.contains(word) then
      add members of L that aren't already there to tobetested
  next
  for each sentence to tobetested ' hopefully much less than 100'000
    compare using your algorithm
  next
next
```

Answer (score 0):

As the data is in the database, can you not do the work in the database?

Shred the sentences to words against sentence row.

Join your words against the shredded words.  This should allow you to see which sentences have a matching word.

If you then group and sum them by the sentence id you should get the sum of words that match in the specified sentence against stored sentences.

I would look to shredding your data beforehand.  Use them as indexes against your main sentence table.